# Youtube LiveChat API: messageTextInvalid

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm using the Youtube livechat.insert API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/insert), and occasionally get back the `messageTextInvalid` error. However the error description page doesn't give much of a hint as to what's wrong here (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/errors#liveChatMessages_youtube.liveChatMessages.insert). I've ensured the messages being sent are <= 200 characters long, and do not have newlines in them. However a message like '(Discord) person: COMMENT : Wonderful!' returns this error that the text is invalid. Is there some information that I can find about what text is valid in the message? I also didn't find much information on the livechat message resource page (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages#resource)

Comment: Same here, I think there was a silent change to the API recently.  I'll post the answer if I ever find one.

Comment: I found out the account I was using to post on before lost access to youtube for some reason, logging into the account normally, then, commenting on the video as a user unlocked the account for API access.